# Pass a list of view models to mvc controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I am having issues serializing my view's data into my viewmodel object and not sure how to resolve the issue. `scoreCards` in the controller action is null when debugging.

controller action:

```
public ActionResult SaveSkeetSinglesScores(SkeetSinglesScoreCards scoreCards) {
        return View();
    }
```

View model containing list passed into controller (`SkeetSinglesScoreCards`):

```
public class SkeetSinglesScoreCards {
    public List<SkeetSinglesScoreCard> scoreCards { get; set; }
}
```

Individual `SkeetSinglesScoreCard` view model:

```
public class SkeetSinglesScoreCard {
    public string sgl_H_1 {get; set; }
    public string sgl_L_1 { get; set; }
    public string dbl_H_1 { get; set; }
    public string dbl_L_1 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_H_2 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_L_2 { get; set; }
    public string dbl_H_2 { get; set; }
    public string dbl_L_2 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_H_3 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_L_3 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_H_4 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_L_4 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_H_5 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_L_5 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_H_6 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_L_6 { get; set; }
    public string dbl_H_6 { get; set; }
    public string dbl_L_6 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_H_7 { get; set; }
    public string sgl_L_7 { get; set; }
    public string dbl_L_7 { get; set; }
    public string dbl_H_7 { get; set; }
    public string H_8 { get; set; }
    public string L_8 { get; set; }
    public string opt { get; set; }
}
```

and finally my view where I am posting data to the controller action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveSkeetSinglesScores", "Scores", FormMethod.Post)) {
    foreach (var round in Model) {
    <table class="table table-bordered">

        <thead>
            <tr class="active">
               <!--table headers here--!>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_H_1")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit1StationOneSinglesHigh)" />
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_L_1")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit2StationOneSinglesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_dbl_H_1")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit3StationOneDoublesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_dbl_L_1")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit4StationOneDoublesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_H_2")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit5StationTwoSinglesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_L_2")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit6StationTwoSinglesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_dbl_H_2")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit7StationTwoDoublesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_dbl_L_2")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit8StationTwoDoublesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_H_3")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit9StationThreeSinglesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_L_3")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit10StationThreeSinglesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_H_4")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit11StationFourSinglesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_L_4")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit12StationFourSinglesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_H_5")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit13StationFiveSinglesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_L_5")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit14StationFiveSinglesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_H_6")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit15StationSixSinglesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_L_6")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit16StationSixSinglesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_dbl_H_6")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit17StationSixDoublesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_dbl_L_6")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit18StationSixDoublesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_H_7")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit19StationSevenSinglesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_sgl_L_7")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit20StationSevenSinglesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_dbl_L_7")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit21StationSevenDoublesLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_dbl_H_7")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit22StationSevenDoublesHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_H_8")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit23StationEightHigh)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"_L_8")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.Hit24StationEightLow)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="@("scoreCards_"+i+"opt")" type="text" maxlength="1" size="1" value="@ScoreHitMisConverter.IsHitToTableRowValue(round.OptionScore)" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-center total">0</td>
                @{i++;}
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

}
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Save">Save</button>
}
```

Comment: For this type of situations I've find that's usually a good idea to translate your viewmodel to JSON and pass it directly as a string to the controller (into an input field, for example). Model binding seems to be more capable to parse JSON strings than complex IEnumerable datatypes.

Comment: @Bardo still a little confused on how to resolve the issue. can you provide an answer for this context on how you would resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code will generate input field's with name like this pattern.

```
scoreCards_0_sgl_H_1
```

But your HttpPost action method accepts an object of `SkeetSinglesScoreCards`, which has a `scorecard` property. So you should generate html like this for model binding to work.

```
<input name="scoreCards[0].sgl_H_1" value="somthing" />
<input name="scoreCards[1].sgl_H_1" value="somthing" />
```

This should work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var skeetSinglesScoreCard in Model.scoreCards)
    {    
        <input name="scoreCards[@i].sgl_H_1" type="text" value="someValue" />
        i++;
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I want to work with complex data types, and I have to manage data collections that have to be passed back to the controller this is how I usually proceed:

1) Create a class for the viewModel (in this case it would be your SkeetSinglesScoreCards).

2) On client code (HTML) I load a JSON version of those data into a hidden input (sometimes the JSON data came from the viewModel class, other times I parse it when rendering the page, it depends on the business model).

3) On client code (javascript) I load the JSON data into a javascript object. Every client operation is taken into account over this object. When I can I totally avoid resending info to server through AJAX until global submit is posted.

4) When the user asks to post the result of his operations I capture the event on javascript, stringify the javascript object where info is stored and post it to the hidden input. Then post the form.

5) Controller signature expects for an element of a class that can be inferred from the data structure stored in the hidden input, and the name of the parameter is the same as the hidden input.

I've found this method to work quite well